# If $|z - 8|=\max\{|z + 2|,|z - 4|\}$ ,then $z$ lies on

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $|z - 8|=\max\{|z + 2|,|z - 4|\}$ ,then $z$ lies on

I just assumed them maximum one by one 
$$\frac{|z - 8|}{|z + 2|}=1$$ 
$$\frac{|z - 8|}{|z  - 4|}=1$$

[image]

So I concluded that $z$ will lie on this pair of staright line but the answer say $z$ lie on a pair of circle.

Comment: What is your source?

Comment: @Did Book..${}{}{}$

Comment: Is this your way of giving a source?

Comment: @Did A book named Comprehensive Mathematics for JEE Advance .

Comment: @Did  https://books.google.co.in/books?id=O7lyCgAAQBAJ&pg=SA1-PA1&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false Page 1.49 Level-2 Question -3

Comment: Well, typo then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitively a typo but your answer is wrong. Try $z = 6$. You have $|z-8| = |z-4| = 2$ but $|z+2| = 8$ and it's the maximum of $\{|z+2|, |z-4|\}$.
In order to solve this equation you have to remove the max. For this, you have to look first in which domain $|z+2|$ and $|z-4|$ are maximum. Then you can solve the problem.